# Cutting/Slicing an HTML document into pieces with BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I have an HTML document as follows:

```
<h1> Name of Article </h2> 
<p>First Paragraph I want</p>
<p>More Html I'm interested in</p>
<h2> Subheading in the article I also want </h2>
<p>Even more Html i want to pull out of the document.</p>
<h2> References </h2> 
<p>Html I do not want...</p>
```

I don't need references from the article, I want to slice the document at the second h2 tag.

Obviously I can find a list of h2 tags like so:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soupset = soup.find_all('h2')
soupset[1] #this would get the h2 heading 'References' but not what comes before it
```

I don't want to get a list of the h2 tags, I want to slice the document right at the second h2 tag and keep the above contents in a new variable. Basically the desired output I want is:

```
<h1> Name of Article </h2> 
<p>First Paragraph I want<p>
<p>More Html I'm interested in</p>
<h2> Subheading in the article I also want </h2>
<p>Even more Html i want to pull out of the document.</p>
```

What is the best way to go aboout doing this "slicing"/cutting of the HTML document instead of simply finding tags and outputing the tags itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [remove/extract](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) every sibling element of the "References" element and the element itself:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <h1> Name of Article </h2>
    <p>First Paragraph I want</p>
    <p>More Html I'm interested in</p>
    <h2> Subheading in the article I also want </h2>
    <p>Even more Html i want to pull out of the document.</p>
    <h2> References </h2>
    <p>Html I do not want...</p>
</div>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

references = soup.find("h2", text=re.compile("References"))
for elm in references.find_next_siblings():
    elm.extract()
references.extract()

print(soup)
```

Prints:

```
<div>
    <h1> Name of Article</h1>
    <p>First Paragraph I want</p>
    <p>More Html I'm interested in</p>
    <h2> Subheading in the article I also want </h2>
    <p>Even more Html i want to pull out of the document.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this should work, thanks!! Greatly appreciated. Very clean. Just to make sure I've clearly understood it, the loop that performs elm.extract() is needed to remove all the html within the h2 tags right? Then the end references.extract() simply removes the 'References' h2 tags after all is extracted from within it?

Comment: @EazyC I hope it helps. In the loop we remove every next sibling to the References element, then we remove the References element itself..

Answer (score 0):

You can find the location of the `h2` in the string and then find a substring by it:

```
last_h2_tag = str(soup.find_all("h2")[-1]) 
html[:html.rfind(last_h2_tag) + len(last_h2_tag)]
```